# Using ImageJ filters directly from Mathematica through J/Link

Tags: image-processing, interoperability, java, external-calls

**tl;dr** I am looking for a short but complete example that shows how to apply an [ImageJ](https://fiji.sc/) filter to a Mathematica [`Image`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Image.html) through [J/Link](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/JLink/tutorial/Overview.html).

---

[Fiji/ImageJ](https://fiji.sc/) is one of the largest and most popular image processing tools.  It is designed to be scriptable and can be used even [interactively through a Jupyter notebook](https://github.com/imagej/tutorials). It supports several languages such as Groovy/Python/Scala/R/Ruby/etc., but not Mathematica.

My aim is to use certain filters from ImageJ through [the Ops framework](https://imagej.net/ImageJ_Ops). I am sure that this is possible through [J/Link](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/JLink/tutorial/Overview.html). Unfortunately, I don't know Java, and I'd need to go through many technical hurdles to get everything working.

I am looking for an answer that would get a typical Mathematica user (with no or minimal Java knowledge) through these technical hurdles. Assume that I downloaded [the Fiji app](https://fiji.sc/) and installed some plugins. What do I need to do to access a filter, such as median, from Mathematica, including setting up classpaths, (re)installing J/Link, and creating the required Java objects before I can call the necessary methods to run the filter?

The Groovy script to do this [might look like this](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/imagej/tutorials/blob/master/notebooks/ImageJ_Tutorials_and_Demo.ipynb):

```java
// Median filter.
median = ij.op().run("create.img", eyes32)
neighborhood = new HyperSphereShape(4)
ij.op().run("filter.median", median, eyes32, neighborhood)
```

Ideally, the `ImageData` would be transferred from Mathematica (here it comes from the `eyes32` variable which was earlier loaded from a file).

---

There is a [closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9107889/695132) on StackOverflow. My question is different because it is specifically about using the Ops API and avoiding writing and compiling Java code (if possible).

---

**Update with current progress and issues:**

The first step is to create the `ij` object used in the tutorial notebooks.

```
Needs["JLink`"]

(* adjust the path to your Fiji *)
AddToClassPath@FileNames["/Users/szhorvat/Desktop/Fiji.app/jars/*"];

LoadJavaClass["com.wolfram.jlink.JLinkClassLoader"]
```

Issue 1: I can't include the crucial `net.imagej.ImageJService` below without triggering an error.

```
context = JavaNew["org.scijava.Context",
  JLinkClassLoader`classFromName /@ {
    (* "net.imagej.ImageJService", *) (* including this results in an error about loading net.imagej.legacy.LegacyService — how can I fix this? *)
    "net.imagej.ops.OpService",
    "io.scif.SCIFIOService",
    "org.scijava.io.IOService",
    "org.scijava.app.StatusService"
    }
  ]

ij = JavaNew["net.imagej.ImageJ", context]
(* JLink`Objects`vm1`JavaObject16280761535561729 *)

io = ij@io[]
(* JLink`Objects`vm1`JavaObject15342879492800513 *)

op = ij@op[]
(* JLink`Objects`vm1`JavaObject1760488337702913 *)

mandrill = io@open["http://imagej.net/images/baboon.jpg"]
(* JLink`Objects`vm1`JavaObject15612747035181057 *)
```

Issue 2: It is unclear to me why the following fails, even though `Methods[op]` does list the `run` and `help` methods.

```
med = op@run["create.img", mandrill]

(* During evaluation of Java::nometh: No method named run defined in class net.imagej.ops.DefaultOpService. *)
(* $Failed *)

op@help["create.img"]

(* During evaluation of Java::nometh: No method named help defined in class net.imagej.ops.DefaultOpService. *)
(* $Failed *)
```

Final remaining task: 1. retrieve the image data from the `mandrill` object 2. create a similar object directly from Mathematica using and `Image`'s `ImageData`.

Comment: I created a chatroom for this topic: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82127/imagej-from-mma I am going to keep dropping bits of information there as I progress towards a solution with this.

Comment: Hi @Szabolcs, did you even manage to interact with ImageJ from Mathematica?

Comment: @rhermans No. It should be possible, but didn't have the time and expertise to figure out all details. Also, ImageJ / Fiji always want to be the centre of your workflow. They do not seem to have good support for being used as a library. The idea is that if you want to use Fiji with "system X", then call "system X" from Fiji instead of calling Fiji from "system X".

Answer (score 7):

This is not an answer to the main question on how to do it in Mathematica but merely one possible reason why this whole thing might not be achievable. In Java, your exact example looks like this

```java
package de.halirutan.ijm;

import java.io.IOException;
import net.imagej.ImageJ;
import net.imglib2.algorithm.neighborhood.HyperSphereShape;

public class TestCase {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final ImageJ ij = new ImageJ();
        final Object mandrill = ij.io().open("http://imagej.net/images/baboon.jpg");
        final Object median = ij.op().run("create.img", mandrill);
        HyperSphereShape neighborhood = new HyperSphereShape(4);
        ij.op().run("filter.median", median, mandrill, neighborhood);
        ij.io().save(median, "median.png");
    }

}
```

This short thing takes almost a full minute to run because setting up all the imagej stuff seems expensive. Nevertheless, it saves successfully the median image of the mandrill.

The question is, why does this command fail in Mathemtica:

```
med = op@run["create.img", mandrill]
```

The reason is simple, because the error message is correct: "No method named run defined in class net.imagej.ops.DefaultOpService". But why does it work in Java then? Because since Java 8 it is possible to **implement** methods directly in an *interface*:

```java
public interface OpEnvironment extends Contextual {

    // code...

    default Object run(String name, Object... args) {
        return run(this.module(name, args));
    }

    // code...
```

So Mathematica sees that there should be a method `run` because the `DefaultOpService` does implement it, but it is not able to call this default interface implementation.

I'm uncertain if this is possible at all in `JLink` but I'm sure, that this is the reason why it doesn't work. It's a Java 8 feature and although my 11.3 installation uses Java 8u152, it seems `JLink` doesn't support it.

Comment: So what remains as an option is writing my own class that wraps the relevant methods, right?

Comment: Or talk to someone from the JLink team. I haven't spent very much time with this, I've seen these "op" things the first time, so there is a good chance I missed something.