# Mathematica for automatic image processing and quantification

Tags: image-processing, image, microscopy

I've been working on image analysis pipeline that involves a set of batch processing macros in ImageJ (for image segmentation) and data processing in Excel (VBA).  I've got the process run in 4-5 clicks.

Is it possible to use Mathematica to run ImageJ and VBA macros and handle directories for multiple image processing?

Thanks

Comment: I think you will need to add significantly more detail to your question to get any meaningful answers. In short, the answer is probably "yes, but why?". Mathematica has good image segmentation and data processing functionality - why delegate to ImageJ and Excel?

Comment: There's both too much and too little in the question. Example of too much: "use Mathematica to run ImageJ and VBA macros and handle directories" These are three independent very broad topics that should have their own questions. Example of too little: "use Mathematica to run ImageJ" What do you want to achieve? Just run an external process? Batch process many images? Exchange data with ImageJ in a structured was and be able to pass and receive an `Image` expression? Etc.

Comment: Regarding interfacing with ImageJ in a flexible way, it's not easy. I gave up on it mostly. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/180513/12 Regarding interfacing with Excel: check out ExcelLink.